# Management Console Error

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm working as an IT Technician for a school at the moment. Sadly, the air-con failed in the server room yesterday so unfortunately we had to shut the servers down. Now, problem is - we've started the servers back up and have an error.

Our students have networked accounts and we control virtually everything from a management console created by RM. We have Server 1 and Server 2 to do this from which we remotely connect to. Now the problem is, when we try to assign a user more disk space for their account - the disk quota isn't there at all? It's saying it's unavailable. We've tried calling support but they haven't solved it yet. Open to any ideas and greatly appreciate your time.

We're using Windows Server 2008 R3 on all our servers.